# How are formulas (of Excel) kept and used in a database?

Tags: sql, vba, database, ms-access

This is a very general question...

Imagine that I have an Excel table with 4 columns:

```
     A    B       C    D
1    year revenue cost benefit
2    2000 155     30   125
3    2001 144     70   74
4    2002 189     40   149
...  ...  ...     ...  ...
```

The column `benefit` is calculated from `revenue` minus `cost`. Thus `D2` has a formula `=B2-C2`; `D3` has a formula `=B3-C3`...

Now I want to convert this table to a database. The database will have 4 fields: `year`, `revenue`, `cost` and `benefit`. It is easy to store the data. However, my question is whether there is somewhere to store the relation `benefit = revenue - cost`?

This relation will be useful. For instance, if I insert a triple `(2015, 222, 45)` as `(year, revenue, cost)`, the `benefit` could be automatically calculated and inserted by the relation and some mechanism.

Could anyone tell me which means a database has to hold relations and automates this kind of thing?

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you had a database table defined with year, revenue and cost columns.

You could run a query to get the computed values such as:

```
select
    year,
    revenue,
    cost,
    revenue - cost as benefit
from
    table
```

In Access, this would be called a query, and the definition can be saved. Queries can be used as the data source for other queries.

Comment: what happens if user changes the formulae?

Answer (score 0):

A MySQL database commonly uses [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) to accomplish things like this.

As a quick example, assuming your database was named `exceldb` you could probably accomplish your goals by running the following query:

```
CREATE TRIGGER myTrigger
  BEFORE INSERT ON exceldb
  FOR EACH ROW
    SET NEW.benefit = NEW.revenue - NEW.cost;
```

After running this query once, the value of `benefit` should automatically be calculated upon each new insertion (without having to "call" or "invoke" the trigger manually).

See [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html) for more info on MySQL trigger syntax.